# Have a question for pygame typewriting effect and the background image

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a question for pygame. I have a project that I am going through which is making my own game and I faced a problem.

I want to place the background image and the typewriting text on top but it is not working. I wish to check these things:

1. check if I have any mistakes
2. The text on top
3. typewriting effect working

```
import pygame
import sys
import random 
from time import sleep
import os


padWidth = 480 #the width the of game 
padHeight = 640 # the length of the game

def drawObject(obj, x, y):
    global gamePad
    gamePad.blit(obj, (int(x), int(y)))

def initGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background
    pygame.init()
    gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((padWidth, padHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Kill The Zombie') #the title of the game
    background = pygame.image.load('ruined.png') #import the background image
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Importing the external screen
os.putenv('SDL_FBDEV', '/dev/fb1')
os.putenv('SDL_MOUSEDRV', 'TSLIB')
os.putenv('SDL_MOUSEDEV', '/dev/input/touchscreen')

#Initializes the screen - Careful: all pygame commands must come after the init
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Sets mouse cursor visibility
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
#Sets the screen note: must be after pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((padWidth, padHeight))


class Board(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((padWidth, padHeight))
        self.image.fill((13,13,13))
        self.image.set_colorkey((13,13,13))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 18)

    def add(self, letter, pos):
        s = self.font.render(letter, 1, (255, 255, 0))
        self.image.blit(s, pos)

class Cursor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, board):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 20))
        self.text_height = 17
        self.text_width = 10
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.text_width, self.text_height))
        self.board = board
        self.text = ''
        self.cooldown = 0
        self.cooldowns = {'.': 12,
                        '[': 18,
                        ']': 18,
                        ' ': 5,
                        '\n': 30}

    def write(self, text):
        self.text = list(text)

    def update(self):
        if not self.cooldown and self.text:
            letter = self.text.pop(0)
            if letter == '\n':
                self.rect.move_ip((0, self.text_height))
                self.rect.x = self.text_width
            else:
                self.board.add(letter, self.rect.topleft)
                self.rect.move_ip((self.text_width, 0))
            self.cooldown = self.cooldowns.get(letter, 8)

        if self.cooldown:
            self.cooldown -= 1

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
board = Board()
cursor = Cursor(board)
all_sprites.add(cursor, board)

text = """Hsdfjsdlkfsdkfooadjasdlsfh sdjfnaldbkjl
jvhisjnljpasihoufjlnjspiho
;ujanjpsidshoujldnahsufbj
"""




cursor.write(text)

#Main loop
runGame = True
def runGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background
    drawObject(background, 0, 0)
    
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    all_sprites.update()
    all_sprites.draw(gamePad)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

initGame()
runGame()
```

The background image appears but the text and the typewriting effect is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your game just exits after the first screen render. You need to add a loop to your main function to continue the game:

```
#Main loop
def runGame():
    running = True
    while (running):   # main loop
        global gamePad, clock, background
        drawObject(background, 0, 0)
        
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        all_sprites.update()
        all_sprites.draw(gamePad)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()   # don't need this
        clock.tick(60)

initGame()
runGame()
```

Comment: wowowowowowow It is working!!! THANK YOU very much for the fast solution!! Thank You very much!